# Emulate a very fast (virtual) CPU core

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, cpu, cpu-architecture

I know that the usual method when we want to make a big math computation faster is to use multiprocessing / parallel processing: we split the job in for example 4 parts, and we let 4 CPU cores run in parallel (parallelization). This is possible for example in Python with `multiprocessing` module: on a 4-core CPU, it would allow to use 100% of the processing power of the computer instead of only 25% for a single-process job.

But let's say we want to make faster a **non-easily-splittable computation job**.
Example: we are given a number generator function `generate(n)` that takes the previously-generated number as input, and "it is said to have 10^20 as period". We want to check this assertion with the following pseudo-code:

```
a = 17
for i = 1..10^20
    a = generate(a)
check if a == 17
```

Instead of having a computer's 4 CPU cores (3.3 Ghz) running "in parallel" with a total of 4 processes, **is it possible to emulate one very fast single-core CPU of 13.2 Ghz** (4*3.3) running one single process with the previous code?

Is such technique available for a desktop computer? If not, is it available on cloud computing platforms (AWS EC2, etc.)?

Comment: Well, if you can split your *non-easily-splittable computation job* into sequential steps you might be able to *pipeline* the computation.  But it seems a little unreasonable to me to first think of a *non-easily-splittable computation job* and then ask how to split it.  I guess the answer must be *not easily*.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Is there no low-level software on Linux for example, that would let the OS think we have 1 single 13.2 Ghz core instead of 4 cores each 3.3Ghz?   (not for general things, but for very specific math computation)?

Comment: What magic could any system have that would split a job which you have stated to be non-splittable ?  Your question doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: That's kind of like saying *"if it takes a mother elephant 20 months to have a baby elephant, can I get my baby elephant in 5 months if there are 4 mother elephants"*.

Comment: @MarkSetchell So for a non-splittable algorithm (e.g. the one I gave the pseudo code), there is no alternative than taking the highest speed Ghz CPU available?

Comment: There is something else: write more efficient code. Although that's not so much an alternative as it is an orthogonal course of action that can and should be combined with also using faster hardware to get the best results.

Answer (score 2):

Single-threaded performance is extremely valuable; it's much easier to write sequential code than to explicitly expose thread-level parallelism.

**If there was an easy and efficient general-purpose way to do what you're asking which works when there is no parallelism in the code, it would already be in widespread use**.  Either internally inside multi-core CPUs, or in software if it required higher-level / larger-scale code transformations.

Out-of-order CPUs can find and exploit instruction-level parallelism within a single thread (over short distances, like a couple hundred instructions), but you need explicit thread-level parallelism to take advantage of multiple cores.

This is similar to [How does a single thread run on multiple cores?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/349972/how-does-a-single-thread-run-on-multiple-cores/350024#350024) over on SoftwareEnginnering.SE, except that you've already ruled out any easy-to-find parallelism including instruction-level parallelism.  (And the answer is: it doesn't.  It's the hardware of a single core that finds the instruction-level parallelism in a single thread; my answer there explains some of the microarchitectural details of how that works.)

The reverse process: turning one big CPU into multiple weaker CPUs does exist, and is useful for running multiple threads which don't have much instruction-level parallelism.  It's called [SMT (Simultaneous MultiThreading)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_multithreading).  You've probably heard of Intel's Hyperthreading, the most widely known implementation of SMT.  It trades single-threaded performance for more throughput, keeping more execution units fed with useful work more of the time.  The cost of building a single wide core grows at least quadratically, which is why typical desktop CPUs don't just have a single massive core with 8-way SMT.  (And note that a really wide CPU still wouldn't help with a totally dependent instruction stream, unless the `generate` function has some internal instruction-level parallelism.)

SMT would be good if you wanted to test 8 different `generate()` functions at once on a quad-core CPU.  Without SMT, you could alternate in software between two `generate` chains in one thread, so out-of-order execution could be working on instructions from both dependency chains in parallel.

---

Auto-parallelization by compilers at compile time is possible for source that has some visible parallelism, but if `generate(a)` isn't "separable" (not the correct technical term, I think) then you're out of luck.

e.g. if it's `return a + hidden_array[static_counter++];` then the compiler can use math to prove that summing chunks of the array in parallel and adding the partial sums will still give the same result.

But if there's truly a serial dependency through `a` (like [even a simple LCG PRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator)), and the software doesn't know any mathematical tricks to break the dependency or reduce it to a closed form, you're out of luck.  Compilers do know tricks like `sum(0..n) = n*(n+1)/2` (evaluated slightly differently to avoid integer overflow in a partial result), or `a+a+a+...` (n times) is `a * n`, but that doesn't help here.

Answer (score 2):

There is a scheme studied mostly in the academy called "Thread Decomposition". It aims to do more or less what you ask about - given a single-threaded code, it tries to break it down into multiple threads in order to divide the work on a multicore system. This process can be done by a compiler (although this requires figuring out all possible side effects at compile time which is very hard), by a JIT runtime, or through HW binary-translation, but each of these methods has complicated limitations and drawbacks.

Unfortunately, other than being automated, this process has very little appeal as it can hardly match true manual parallelization done by a person how understands the code. It also doesn't simply scale performance according to the number of threads, since it usually incurs a large overhead in the form of code that has to be duplicated.

Example paper by some nice folks from UPC in Barcelona: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/5260571/

Comment: And when there is no coarse-grained parallelism (like in this case), then there's of course nothing that a compiler / JIT / HW can do.  It only works when there is some large-scale parallelism to be found.

Comment: True, of course something like a plain old pointer chasing case would be impossible to parallelize, but I was surprised to see how much these methods do cover. I think something around ~90% of spec06 dynamic code can be covered to some extent (can't find a link for that though). Of course it's a tradeoff of how much code are you willing to duplicate (thereby reducing the gain) to avoid unnecessary communication.